# MySQL column with duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I have a string column which has duplicate values, for example

```
row 1 column "desc" has value -> "stack-overflow stack-overflow"
```

I want to update the column to "stack-overflow"

any idea how to build a query for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duplicate record must be symmetric and should be  repeated twice only then following will do the trick

```
select 
    left 
        (
          'stack-overflow stack-overflow',
          length('stack-overflow stack-overflow')/2
        )
```